# How to triplicate and rearrange columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame containing 10 columns (Reporter_intensity_corrected_0 to Reporter_intensity_corrected_9) and I want each column triplicated while rearranging the column sequence (original column followed by triplicated columns).

Example:

From this:

```
Reporter_intensity_corrected_0   Reporter_intensity_corrected_1 ...  
                           245                             123  
                           357                             984
```

To this:

```
Reporter_intensity_corrected_0   Reporter_intensity_corrected_0 Reporter_intensity_corrected_0
                           245                              245                            245
                           357                              357                            357
```

How can I do this?

I've tried this option:

```
df1<- df[rep(names(df),c(3))]
```

but this resulted in the columns arranged as Reporter_intensity_corrected_0:9 repeated 3 times instead of the example above.

I feel like I am missing some comments but I do not know which.

Thanks.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example and expected result

Comment: I think you need `each` argument, try this example: `x <- mtcars[1:3, 1:2]; x[ rep(names(x), each = 4) ]` , and repeat each 4 times instead of 3, so you have "original" column then tripled ones.

Comment: @Sotos  Hey, I just edited the question. I am not sure how to share a reproducible example but hopefully my edited explanation is clear enough. Thanks!

Comment: So the code given to you by @zx8754 at comment above should work for you. Note that you cant have the same column names so It will automatically assign them  a suffix

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you! Much appreciated